# In CQ How disable the topmost node of a tag

Tags: content-management-system, aem

Is there any way to disable the topmost node of a tag when I am adding a tag.

It is like suppose I have a dialog in which there is a field with xtype= tags and the tag is XYZ under which A, B, C are child nodes.

I want the author to select only A or B or C. He can not select XYZ.

How can I implement this. in the tagging_field.js

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying after long time, this might be helpful for others. This can be achieved something like this, if the user/author selects xyz tag the value gets added to the tag field, you can get the array of values added in the tag field using getValue method and if the array contains the xyz value delete the value and setValue back to the tag field using setValue method

Here is the link to API docs for tag field for you to refer. [Tag Field API Docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.tagging.TagInputField)

Regards,
Yash Ahuja.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yash, but I wanted some thing else. Its like, author can't even select the first node. when he clicks subnodes will expanded but parent node wont be selectable

Comment: In that case I will suggest you to check the Widget API Docs first, there could be some way to achieve this I am not sure which configuration, otherwise the only option left is to customize the Tag input widget again you can see the code of TagInputField.js in crx /libs/cq/tagging/widgets/source/widgets/TagInputField.js.